# How to wrap text of large headings in dataset?

Tags: dataset

I am trying to achieve the following effect produced in Excel in Wolfram Dataset:

[image]

The following attempt doesn't work:

```
Dataset[
    {<|"small column"->123,"very large column heading"->123|>,<|"small column"->45678910,"very large column heading"->456|>,<|"small column"->789,"very large column heading"->78910|>},
    HeaderDisplayFunction->(Style[#,AutoIndent->True,LineIndent->0,TextAlignment->Center]&)
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap the text in [`Pane`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pane.html) with an `UpTo` style width specification to get the wrapping, and use `HeaderAlignment` for the centering:

```
automatic = Automatic;
Dataset[{<|"small column" -> 123, 
   "very large column heading" -> 123|>, <|"small column" -> 45678910,
    "very large column heading" -> 456|>, <|"small column" -> 789, 
   "very large column heading" -> 78910|>}, 
 HeaderDisplayFunction -> (Style[Pane[#, {UpTo@75, Automatic}], 
     TextAlignment -> Center, LineBreakWithin -> automatic] &), 
 HeaderAlignment -> {Center, Center}]
```

[image]

Note the use of [`LineBreakWithin`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineBreakWithin.html) to allow the header lines to actually wrap (thanks @lericr for pointing out that it doesn't work on desktop otherwise!). The last thing needed to make this work is using `automatic` as value for `LineBreakWithin` - this is due to a bug in `HeaderDisplayFunction`, which replaces any literal `Automatic` with `Nothing` (which would break the option). To work around this, I simply hide `Automatic` by using a variable.

Comment: Surprisingly, this doesn't work for me with version 13.2. The text is simply truncated, not wrapped. The Pane works fine on its own, just not inside the HeaderDisplayFunction option.

Comment: Interesting... I wrote this answer on my phone, and there it works as expected - I never would have thought that the wolfram cloud app does something "better" than the desktop app. Anyways, I have updated the answer with a fixed version

Answer (score 5):

One could use `ToString` with `PageWidth` options. Since it adds two `\n`, we'll do a little post-processing:

```
Dataset[ ... , 
 HeaderDisplayFunction -> 
  (StringReplace[ToString[#, PageWidth -> 15], "\\\n" -> ""] &)]
```

Result:

[image]